# Units of angular power spectrum

Tags: units, cosmic-microwave-background, spherical-harmonics

I am not sure whether this question might be better suited for crossvalidated or stackoverflow, but I will give it a try here:

I have a map of the full sky in in the [healpix](http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov) format, units are $\rm MJy\, sr^{-1}$ (definition of $\rm Jy$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jansky)). To compute the angular power spectrum i.e. the $C_l$, I use the function [anafast](http://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/healpy.sphtfunc.anafast.html) from the [healpy](http://healpy.readthedocs.org) library.

Now, I *think* that the resulting $C_l$ have units of $(\rm MJy\,sr^{-1})^2\, sr$, but I could not find anything on the units in the literature so far.

I'd very much appreciate any help regarding the units or links to familiarise myself further with this topic.